# why entry control is not displaying on UI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app in Xamarin.Forms by PCL.

I want to display the Textbox but this is not displaying on UI.

Can you tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Below is my XAML code

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="layoutouterFrame" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <!--<Frame Padding = "5" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">-->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid x:Name="grid">

            </Grid>
            <Entry x:Name="txtentry" FontSize="Medium" Margin="0,25" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="100"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"    />
        </StackLayout>
    <!--</Frame>-->
</StackLayout>
```

In the Grid, I am binding the control at runtime that is displaying properly. But issue with the Entry control.

Comment: Entry is Rendered but its not in your showing area..... just remove all the layout and see which layout it takes out

Comment: LIkely, the Entry is being rendered off of the right side of the screen. The Grid may be consuming the screen size and the Entry is being rendered to the right of the Grid, off of the screen.